# JQuery Handsontable - remove_col not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, handsontable

I am in a situation where I need to be able to remove/hide columns dynamically. I found what I think should do the trick in the [Methods](https://github.com/warpech/jquery-handsontable/wiki/Methods) section in the handsontable documentation. But have I have not been able to get it to work. I keep getting an error that says "**Uncaught Error: cannot remove column with object data source or columns option specified**".

I am trying to use the "alter" method with "remove_col" to remove the column.

```
$("#EFTable").handsontable('getInstance').alter('remove_col', 3)
```

[Here](http://jsfiddle.net/zamhick/fFSrK/2/) is a sample of the code I am working with in JSFiddle.

Any suggestions on how to make this work or an other direction to get the job done would be appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

I looked at this again this morning and saw that the answer was right in front of me. The error message told me "cannot remove column with object data source or columns option specified". The second part was the answer.

I am using the "columns" option to control the function of each column. You can't use the remove_col method when you are using the columns option.

Comment: How did you change your code so that you didn't need to use the columns option.

Comment: Ridiculous, isn't it?  I'm making a custom function to add / remove columns as a result.

Comment: can you share that custom function and where it's being called/wired up?